# Nested_form for single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a rails 4 app where I have a Product Model that has columns: Title (string), Description (text), and Data (text, but I'm storing JSON inside).

What I'm trying to do is similar to what the nested_form gem (by Ryan Bates) provides. I've been searching but can't seem to find a way to have multiple fields, say I want to store inside the data column a json object of color:blue and size:big.

I have inside my _form:

`<input type='text name="product[data][]">`

but I'm getting the error:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WHzAChBlWH6bOSUzUp50sSTt1hm/6/Uruuy7TY4LY8I=", "product"=>{"title"=>"fdsaf", "data"=>["fsdsadfsdf", "fasdfsdf"]}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
Unpermitted parameters: data`

Basically my question is how can I using rails generate a text field for color and size (but  could be anything) that then save as JSON? Similar to how the nested_form gem allows you to have a "Add Field"?

Comment: Can you show us your controller code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not added the data field in strong parameters, This might work  and wont give the above error.

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, data: [])
```